# Is there a way to automate the presentation of pandas Dataframes in an attractive manner

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

An important component of my job is presenting data tables in an attractive manner.  I do a lot of work in Pandas and usually have to export to Excel and work on the presentation in there.  Does anyone know of any way to present Pandas Data frames in attractive looking tables?

Answer (score 2):

I like the approach that @[Brandon Rhodes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85360/brandon-rhodes) takes in his excellent [pandas tutorial](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial). He uses the IPython Notebook, and at the beginning of his notebooks, he adds the lines:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
css = open('style-table.css').read() + open('style-notebook.css').read()
HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(css))
```

which references the files `style-notebook.css` and `style-table.css` in the project directory.  Those files (which can be found on his [github page](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial)) can be modified as you like, but here's what his look like.

style-notebook.css:

```
h3 {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

style-table.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
table.dataframe {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}
table.dataframe tr {
    border: none;
}
table.dataframe td, table.dataframe th {
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding-left: 0.25em;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
}
table.dataframe th:not(:empty) {
    background-color: #fec;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
table.dataframe tr:nth-child(2) th:empty {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px dashed #888;
}
table.dataframe td {
    border: 2px solid #ccf;
    background-color: #f4f4ff;
}
```

The resulting tables look very nice; for example:

[image: pretty df table after Brandon Rhodes]